# user defined functon not working for file uploading

Tags: php

I am trying to upload multiple files on a page. So instead of writing code 4 times, I made a function. But the function isn't working.
I have 4 input tags with type file ande names file1, file2 and so on.
the function is as below.

```
if ($_POST['title']!="") {
    function fileup($filen,$n){
            $name[$n]= $_FILES[$filen]['name'];
            $tmp_name= $_FILES[$filen]['tmp_name'];
            $path= "../gallery/".$name[$n];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path);
            return $path;
    }
    $product_image1 = fileup('file1','1');//calling function
    $product_image2 = fileup('file2','2');
    $product_image3 = fileup('file3','3');
    $product_image4 = fileup('file4','4');
        $ins="insert into product set product_category='".$_POST['category']."',
                                        product_title='".$_POST['title']."',
                                        product_description='".$_POST['description']."',
                                        product_code='".$_POST['code']."',
                                        product_price='".$_POST['price']."',
                                        product_image1='".$name1."',
                                        product_image2='".$name2."',
                                        product_image3='".$name3."',
                                        product_image4='".$name4."',
                                        product_status='".$_POST['status']."',
                                        product_fru='".$_POST['fru']."'
                                        ";
        mysqli_query($conn,$ins);
    }
```

I do have enctype="multipart/form-data" in form
and input tags for files are as below

```
<input type="file" name="file1">
<input type="file" name="file2">
<input type="file" name="file3">
<input type="file" name="file4">
```

Comment: what error are you getting....?

Comment: check your codes, there are lots of errors in there, like echo usage, fileN undefined constants, etc

Comment: yes it is giving error for echo only

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Metro_Mall_Project\admin\add_products.php on line 7

Comment: line 7 = line 2 in above code

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php is a language construct. you shouldn't concatenate it on anything. variables are preceded by '$' sign, otherwise, you're referencing to a constant.

Comment: you need to understand what should be the echo syntax and how it works, really you embarrassed echo by using it like $name.echo 'n' and $name.echo n

Comment: seriously what's `'".$name1."'`?

Comment: changes made as suggested by few of you but it is still not uploading image also now not giving any error

Comment: what's the source form? does the form have a **multipart/formdata** value on enctype attribute?

Comment: yes rai it do have

Comment: @AnilSangwa **stop** what you are doing right now, read https://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-Programming-Dummies-Wallace-Wang/dp/0470088702 and  https://www.amazon.com/MySQL-Development-All-Reference-Dummies/dp/0470167777 then continue what you are doing

Comment: @madalinivascu  thanks for suggestion, can oyu solve current problem?

Comment: @AnilSangwa i can't give you money to buy those books, go to a library maybe you will find some hard copies of those books

Answer (score 0):

remove **all** the echo's:

```
$name =$_FILES[$filen]['name'];//$name is a local variable so you don't need a custom variable name
$tmp_name=$_FILES[$filen]['tmp_name'];
$path="../gallery/".$name;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path);
```

echo  is a language construct and $name is a variable, you can't concatenate both,in the array of files the key has to be a string not a language construct

i think you want to call the input name as a string not as a constant

```
        fileup('file1',1);//calling function
        fileup('file2',2);
        fileup('file3',3);
        fileup('file4',4);
```

you will need the path for you to insert in the db so you need to return it from the function

```
 function fileup($filen,$n){
                $name[$n]= $_FILES[$filen]['name'];
                $tmp_name= $_FILES[$filen]['tmp_name'];
                $path= "../gallery/".$name[$n];
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path);
                return $path;
        }
        $product_image1 = fileup('file1','1');//calling function
        $product_image2 = fileup('file2','2');
        $product_image3 = fileup('file3','3');
        $product_image4 = fileup('file4','4');
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in D:\xampp\htdocs\Metro_Mall_Project\admin\add_products.php on line 7

Comment: – madalinivascu still not working, also no giving any error

Comment: then that means you either don't have permissions to upload or you didn't post the files correctly

Comment: please check again above code, hope you will understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
function fileup($filen,$n){
                    $name[$n] = $_FILES[$filen]['name'];
                    $tmp_name = $_FILES[$filen]['tmp_name'];
                    $path     = "../gallery/".$name[$n];

                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path);
            }

            fileup(file1,1);//calling function
            fileup(file2,2);
            fileup(file3,3);
            fileup(file4,4);
```

Comment: fileN on calling functions references to a constant. enclose it on quotes

Comment: your code isn't giving error but also not uploading file

Comment: TroubleShoot #1: Are you using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in html form tag ?

Comment: @AbhilashNayak yes <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">